# ValueError: 'Lengths must match to compare' when comparing same length columns

Tags: python, pandas

I just started learning Python and I am trying to do some data analysis with Pandas.

I am trying to apply a filter to a data frame with multiple conditions, but I keep getting the error:

```
        ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (800,), (1,))
```

df has 800 rows, and I am conditioning values in 3 of the 12 columns.

I checked if there was any NaN and zeroes in those columns ( as I am assuming it could be a potential problem when checking the conditions) and  all of the 800 rows are filled with according values.

Here is the code:

```
 df.loc[(df['Type 1']== ['Fire']) & (df['HP'] >70) & (df['Legendary'] == False)]
```

I looked for an answer in later posts and although I found posts about the same error,they were not able to explain the reason for this case specifically in my understanding, as this one seems so much simpler to solve.

p.s: yes. I am learning Pandas doing analysis with a Pokemon data set.

Thanks as lot guys!

Comment: Did you try: `df.loc[(df['Type 1'] == 'Fire') & (df['HP'] > 70) & (df['Legendary'] == False)]`?

Comment: @nonDucor, yes, that is what I tried and got the error message.

Comment: The code on your question is different. Please put in your question what you've actually tried.

Comment: @nonDucor, my bad, you are right, your code is different ( I specified df ['Type 1] == ['Fire'] instead  of == 'Fire' ),I tried yours and it worked, thanks a lot! I did not expect that this error was related to syntax, but it makes sense since now

Comment: The error is not related to syntax actually. Both are correct (syntactically) but mean different things: you were comparing with a list of strings, that happened to contain a single string. But you wanted to compare with only a single string. It makes sense to allow both, as you may want to compare two columns to see which elements are equal (that was the meaning of the first error message you got).